# Displaying table with radio group, internal server error - Shapelets-Platform

Tags: python, dataframe, function, radio-group

I am coming here for another question related to the Shapelets platform. I was trying to improve my data app by displaying my data frame on the dashboard, and since I have a lot of features, I wanted to create a radio group that would select only a specific substrate of my data frame. Unfortunately for me, I haven’t been able to make it work. Everything is working perfectly (I have my initial table, the radio group, etc…), however every time I am selecting an option I have this error: Error: Internal Server Error. Runtime error executing print_selected_option_1
 
Here is my code:

```py
 
def print_selected_option_1(radio: str):
    for i in categories:
         if i == radio:
             selected_cat = categories[i]
    table1 = app.table(data=selected_cat)
    return table1
 
radiogroup= app.radio_group(categories)
app.place(radiogroup)
table = app.table(data=data)
table.bind(print_selected_option_1, radiogroup)
app.place(table)
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you're trying to return a dataframe, but I have a suggestion that might make things easier for you. Instead of returning a dataframe, you can directly return it as a table using the specific module for that in Shapelets: from shapelets.apps import Table. This can simplify your code and enhance its readability.

Check out which variable type is allowed in a table widget on the table module for seamless integration https://shapelets.io/doc/reference/generated/shapelets.apps.DataApp.table.html